# Why does my code keep printing twice? I don't understand the problem

Tags: c, printf, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 1024

int main(){ 

char input_name_string[MAX_STRING_LENGTH+1],motive_string[MAX_STRING_LENGTH+1];
printf("What is your name?\n");
scanf("%1024s",input_name_string);
printf("your name is %s \n", input_name_string);
printf("What is your motive?\n");
scanf(" %1024s",motive_string);
printf("your motive is %s \n", motive_string);
return 0; }
```

So I wrote this simple program for a project in school to try and learn how scanf and printf work. For some reason when this runs it prints the first word in each string on one line then the second word on another line. I don't understand why this is happening? I don't have experience in C but the logic in my code seems correct? Any suggestions

Comment: `scanf` should never be used for interactive input.

Comment: @kaz what do you mean by interactive input?  What specific use case `scanf` solves?

Comment: Interactive input is terminal - everything you put from keyboard into your program. Non-interactive would be if it was piped. For example `$ cat .profile | my_processing_prog`. Then you could use scanf() as `cat` standard output is `my_processing_prog` standard input.

Comment: @TruthSeeker `scanf` is for scanning formatted input prepared for the machine in advance. For instance, formatted data prepared in files, or coming from other programs. Interactive input  means from a user interacting with the program. When the input is incorrect, the stream is left in an unexpected state from which it is hard to recover in any user-friendly way. In particular, any excess characters that are not matched by a failing `scanf` stay in the stream and confuse subsequent `scanf` calls. Programs that take user input have to be much more forgiving.

Comment: @kaz. Thanks for the information. But I am quite surprised,  Why all textbooks and reference books don't mention this!

Comment: @TruthSeeker The K&R2 book says this: *"`scanf` ignores blanks and tabs in its format string. Furthermore, it skips over white space (blanks, tabs, newlines, etc.) as it looks for input values. To read input whose format is not fixed, it is often best to read a line at a time, then pick it apart with `sscanf`."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `scanf` with the conversion format specifier used by you reads characters until a white space character is encountered.

Instead use the function `fgets`.

For example

```
fgets( input_name_string, sizeof( input_name_string ), stdin );
```

The function can append also the new line character to the entered string. To remove it you can write

```
#include <string.h>

/ …

input_name_string[ strcspn( input_name_string, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

As for you format specifier

```
scanf("%1024s",input_name_string);
```

than in any case it is incorrect. Instead of 1024 as the field width should be one less than the size of the character array to reserve one character for the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

You could write

```
scanf( "%1023[^\n]\n", input_name_string );
```

Comment: Actually it answers the question "what to do to make it work" and does it right but not why.

Comment: @tansy Reread one more the answer especially the first statement.

Comment: I did and still don't see the answer why is ("conceptually") `scanf("%s", "Aaa Bbb");` writing `"Bbb"` into `motive_string` (that's how it looks like from output).

Comment: @tansy For starters the shown by you call is incorrect and secondly read one more the first statement of my answer.

Comment: Corrected former comment - what I meant was that input is "Aaa Bbb"<enter> and it will "jump" into second printf() and print "Bbb".

Comment: @tansy You have the third and the ,last attempt to read the first statement of my answer.

Comment: So, what is the clue? That scanf() reads until white character? It still does not explain why "Bbb" is printed @ `printf(..., motive_string);`

Comment: @tansy You have an input buffer containing two words separated by a space and two calls of scanf. What will be outputted?

Comment: Two input buffers and two output buffers. That's why I don't get it.

Comment: @tansy No, you have only *one* input stream, and *two* buffers as variables. Where, do you think, are two input buffers?

Comment: I get it now. I had to made it to write these buffers int files so I could see what's going on on each and every step. 
I stand corrected.

Comment: Btw. `scanf( "%1023[^\n]\n", input_name_string );` requires pressing `^D` (Ctrl+d) to indicate end of input.

Comment: @tansy Neither ^d is required. There are only two calls of scanf.

Comment: Ok, it will wait for second <enter> but it won't show `printf("What is your motive?\n");` until second line is provided.